# How to bind multiple widgets with one "bind" in Tkinter?

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, bind

I am wondering how to bind multiple widgets with one "bind".

For expample:

I have three buttons and I want to change their color after hovering.

```
from Tkinter import *

def SetColor(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="red")
    return

def ReturnColor(event):
    event.widget.config(bg="white")
    return

root = Tk()

B1 = Button(root,text="Button 1", bg="white")
B1.pack()

B2 = Button(root, text="Button2", bg="white")
B2.pack()

B3 = Button(root, text= "Button 3", bg="white")
B3.pack()

B1.bind("<Enter>",SetColor)
B2.bind("<Enter>",SetColor)
B3.bind("<Enter>",SetColor)

B1.bind("<Leave>",ReturnColor)
B2.bind("<Leave>",ReturnColor)
B3.bind("<Leave>",ReturnColor)

root.mainloop()
```

And my goal is to have only two binds (for "Enter" and "Leave" events) instead of six as above.

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for b in [B1, B2, B3]:
    b.bind("<Enter>", SetColor)
    b.bind("<Leave>", ReturnColor)
```

You could go further and abstract all of your snippet:

```
for s in ["button 1", "button 2", "button 3"]:
    b=Button(root, text=s, bg="white")
    b.pack()
    b.bind("<Enter>", SetColor)
    b.bind("<Leave>", ReturnColor)
```

Now it's easy to add extra buttons (just add another entry to the input list). It's also easy to change what you do to all the buttons by changing the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, you can set the parameters using a nested dictionary: `bParams = {'button1': {'bg': 'red', 'command' = self.frame.quit, ...}, ...}`. I'm not sure if you could add the commands in the dictionary, but otherwise, you can do: `b=Button(root, text=s, bg= bParams[b], ...)`.

Answer (score 11):

To answer your specific question on whether you can have a single binding apply to multiple widgets, the answer is yes. It will probably result in more lines of code rather than less, but it's easy to do.

All tkinter widgets have something called "bindtags". Bindtags are a list of "tags" to which bindings are attached. You use this all the time without knowing it. When you bind to a widget, the binding isn't actually on the widget per se, but on a tag that has the same name as the widget's low level name. The default bindings are on a tag that is the same name as the widget class (the underlying class, not necessarily the python class). And when you call `bind_all`, you're binding to the tag `"all"`.

The great thing about bindtags is that you can add and remove tags all you want. So, you can add your own tag, and then assign the binding to it with `bind_class` (I don't know why the Tkinter authors chose that name...).

An important thing to remember is that bindtags have an order, and events are handled in this order. If an event handler returns the string `"break"`, event handling stops before any remaining bindtags have been checked for bindings.

The practical upshot of this is, if you want other bindings to be able to override these new bindings, add your bindtag to the end. If you want your bindings to be impossible to be overridden by other bindings, put it at the start.

## Example

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # add bindings to a new tag that we're going to be using
        self.bind_class("mytag", "<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind_class("mytag", "<Leave>", self.on_leave)

        # create some widgets and give them this tag
        for i in range(5):
            l = tk.Label(self, text="Button #%s" % i, background="white")
            l.pack(side="top")
            new_tags = l.bindtags() + ("mytag",)
            l.bindtags(new_tags)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        event.widget.configure(background="bisque")

    def on_leave(self, event):
        event.widget.configure(background="white")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    view = Example()
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

A little bit more information about bindtags can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432

Also, the `bindtags` method itself is documented on the effbot [Basic Widget Methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bindtags-method) page among other places.