# How do I get this program to successfully run?

Tags: python

I am learning python through a book, and there is a code for a simplified version of Pong. I wrote the code and I am getting continued error messages. Can anyone help? I am using 3.9.2 and attaching the code and error messages below.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3,-2,-1, 1,2,3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x=starts[0]
        self.y=-3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False
    
    def hit_paddle(self,pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False
    

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,200,300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Keypress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Keypress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
       
    def turn_left(self,evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self,evt):
        self.x = 2





tk=Tk()
tk.title=('Game')
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/bennettsullivan/Documents/BOUNCE!!!.py", line 77, in 
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
File "/Users/bennettsullivan/Documents/BOUNCE!!!.py", line 48, in **init**
self.canvas.bind_all('', self.turn_left)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1406, in bind_all
return self._bind(('bind', 'all'), sequence, func, add, 0)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1346, in _bind
self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Keypress"

Comment: I think it's better to use the ``Pygame`` module in python rather than ``Tkinter`` to make better games in Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895877/tkinter-cant-bind-arrow-key-events The answers to this question might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is inside your `Paddle` class. Your event bindings should be camel-case (eg. `<KeyPress-Left>` instead of `<Keypress-Left>`). After capitalizing the 'p,' the program runs fine (just need a way to replay the game or close it properly).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answers your question sufficiently, don't forget to approve it. Glad I could help, and keep up the good work!