# Remove tkinter text default binding

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm making a simple tkinter Text editor, but i want all default bindings of the **Text widget** removed if possible.

For example when i press **Ctrl + i** it inserts a Tab character by default.
I made an event binding that prints how many lines are in the text box, I set the event binding to **Ctrl + i** as well.

When i run it, It prints the number of lines inside the text box, but also inserts a tab character.

I want to know how i can **Overwrite** the default bindings, or learna  way how to remove all the default bindings.

Heres my code btw:

```
from tkinter import *

class comd: # Contains primary commands
    # Capital Rule ----------------------------
    # G = Get | I = Insert | D = Draw | S = Set
    # -----------------------------------------

    def Ggeo(self): # Get Geometry (Get window geometry)
        x = root.winfo_width()
        y = root.winfo_height()
        print("Current Window Geometry")
        print(str(x) + " x " +str(y))

    def Idum(self): # Insters "Dummy Insert"
        import tkinter as tkin
        tbox.insert(INSERT, "Dummy Insert")

    def Ilim(self): # Prints How many lines are in
        info =  int(tbox.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
        print(info)



root = Tk()
root.geometry("885x600-25-25")

tbox = Text(root, font=("Courier","14","bold"))
tbox.pack(expand = True , fill = BOTH)


# Problem here --------------------
tbox.bind("<Control-i>", comd.Ilim)
# ---------------------------------


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can overwrite a binding by having your function return the string `"break"`. For example:

```
def Ilim(self): # Prints How many lines are in
    info =  int(tbox.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
    print(info)
    return "break"
```

If you want to completely remove all bindings (**including the bindings that allow you to insert characters**), that can be easily accomplished. All of the bindings are associated with a "bind tag" (or "bindtag"). If you remove the bindtag, you remove the bindings.

For example, this removes all of the default bindings:

```
    bindtags = list(tbox.bindtags())
    bindtags.remove("Text")
    tbox.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
```

For more information on bind tags, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432