# Python: Tkinter: Delay When Inserting Into Entry Field Using Tree Item Property

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-entry

I've got a bit of code that is suppose to change the text displayed in the entry fields depending on which item is selected in the tree view. I've bound the event to both the left mouse and up and down arrow keys and it's sort of working. Problem is the item in the tree that is currently selected isn't the value being displayed in the entry field. If there are three (5, 7, 4) values and the item with value 4 is selected, the entry field will display the item with value 7 in it. It's always one off. I hate to ask a question about this because I feel like the answer is so simple but I'm really at a loss. Here is my code.

```
    # create GUI items to populate frames
    self.create_menu()
    self.create_edit_display()
    self.albumDisplay = Label(self.editFrame)
    self.create_import_display()
    self.tree.bind("<BackSpace>", self.delete_insert)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-1>", self.update_editFrame)
    self.tree.bind("<Up>", self.update_editFrame)
    self.tree.bind("<Down>", self.update_editFrame)

# selected track can be removed
def delete_insert(self, event):
    self.tree.delete(self.tree.focus())

def update_editFrame(self, event):

    trackInfo = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())
    print(trackInfo)

    if self.tree.focus():
        trackInfo = self.tree.item(self.tree.focus())

        self.trackNumberEntry.delete(0, END)
    #self.trackNumberEntry.insert(0, random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
        self.trackNumberEntry.insert(0, trackInfo['values'][0])
    else:
        self.tree.focus_get()
```

Through my debugging I've noticed that every time I first click on the tree view I get something like.

```
{'tags': '', 'text': '', 'values': '', 'image': '', 'open': 0}
{'tags': '', 'text': 'IMPORT# 2', 'values': [6, 'Supersymmetry', '', 'Arcade     Fire', 'Arcade Fire', 'Reflektor', '', '', 2013, '00:11:16', '', '', 'arcade_fire_reflektor_06_supersymmetry_.mp3', 'arcade_fire_reflektor.jpg', ''], 'image': '', 'open': 0}
```

It's that initial call that's messing up the order. I'm not sure why it's doing that before getting right into 'value''s values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to bind to `<<TreeviewSelect>>` instead of binding to all the ways that the current item can be changed.

The reason your bindings always seem to be one behind is that they are. Custom bindings on widgets fire *before* the built-in bindings, and it is the built-in bindings which change the selected item. Thus, in your callbacks you are seeing the state of the tree before the selected item is changed.

For a longer explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432

Comment: I've read through the longer explanation but am still not sure I understand. I'm not seeing how swapping out the other events for <<TreeviewSelect>> fixes it. I'll give it a go though, so if I'm understanding correctly, the custom bindings are being called before the content in my function update editFrame which is causing it to lag behind? By using <<TreeviewSelect>> I'm gaining access to the built-in bindings for tree view so effectively I'm binding my custom binding to the built-in binding which will have access to the most up to date state of the tree? Which is why it's it now working?

Comment: Using `<<TreeviewSelect>>` works because that event is generated _after_ the selection changes. It is specifically designed to let you know when the selection changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bryan!