# Different results on different ways of binding?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

In the code below I bind keys to a text widget. Depending on the way the binding is done I get a different result when an 'x' is typed in the widget.

Why is there a difference in the output between bind and bind_all?
How should I use all three variants so they all give the same result?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Q_bind(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Text.__init__(self)

        self.bind("<Key>", self._insert_a)    #-> 'a\nx' with break a!
        #self.bind_class("<Key>", self._insert_a) # -> 'x' Replace with:
        #self.bind_class("Text", "<Key>", self._insert_a) # -> 'a'!!
        #self.bind_all("<Key>", self._insert_a)   # -> 'xa\n'
        print(self.bindtags())           #shows the bind-tags

    def _insert_a(self, event=None):
        print(event.char)
        self.insert('end' ,"a\n")
        return 'break'              #added

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Q_bind()
    app.pack(fill="both", expand='y')
    app.master.geometry('400x400')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: different bindings are for different purpose and they work in different way (they can be executed in different moment when `mainloop` checks bindings). http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: btw: it should be `self.bind_class("Text", "<Key>", self._insert_a)` - with class name "Text"

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432

Comment: Not completely @Bryan. After reading the explanation I changed the sample (@furas) and now both bind and bind_class work as I expected. I'll try: press x goes to the widget level and normally invokes the 'x', but as it encounters a break it does nothing and goes to the 'next' level, being the class binding. That will print the "a". "x" is lost on the way. Bind_all ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use all three bindings and get the same result<sup>1</sup> because the result is dependent on the ordering of the widget *bind tags*.

Every widget has an ordered set of *bind tags*. Bindings are actually attached to these tags rather than the actual widget. It just so happens that the first bind tag is the name of the widget.

By default a widget has the following bind tags in the following order:

1. the widget itself
2. the widget class (internal tk class, not tkinter class)
3. the widget toplevel (or root window)
4. "all"

When an event occurs on a widget, the following four things happen:

1. if the widget has a binding that matches the event, process that binding
2. if the widget *class* has a binding that matches the event, process that binding
3. if the widget's toplevel (or root) has a binding that matches the event, process that binding
4. if there is a binding on "all", process that event.

At any time, if a binding returns the literal string `"break"`, no more bindings will be processed. Without returning `"break"`, all four of the event handlers are processed. In the case of your widget binding returning `"break"`, the class, toplevel and "all" bindings won't be processed.

In the specific case of binding `<Key>` with `bind_all`, this is what happens:

1. the widget has no binding that matches the event, so nothing is done
2. the widget class **has** a binding, so it is processed. In this case a letter for the key is inserted into the widget
3. the widget's toplevel/root has no binding, so nothing is done
4. the "all" tag has a binding so it will insert `"a\n"`.

Because the binding for `"all"` happens *after* the binding for the widget class, returning `"break"` has no effect, and cannot prevent the default behavior of inserting an "a" *in addition to* your custom behavior.

Bind tags are a stunningly beautiful way of handling events. I've used at least half a dozen different GUI toolkits in several different languages over the course of many years, and nothing comes close to the power of tk's bind tags mechanism.

---

<sup>1</sup> You actually *can* get the same behavior for all three by adding or removing bind tags, or changing the order of the bind tags. You do this with the `bindtag` method. There is rarely a need to do so, but it is remarkably handy for some special cases.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan for a real explanation, with this I can visualise the process although it may take some more time to really digest. Much appreciated.