# Remove letter from python text widget using bind function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have just started to create a simple text editor. I have already bound a couple of functions to certain keypresses and now I'm trying to add a function that operates on the Return delete being pressed. The aim is to remove the last character entered into the text widget. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))

def addchar(event):
    w.insert(END, event.char)

def deletechar(event):
    current = w.get()
    new = current[:-1]
    w.delete(0,END)
    w.insert(END, new)

def savefile(event):
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    if file is None:
        return
    text2save = str(w.get())
    file.append(data)
    file.close()


 w = Entry(root, bd=1)
 w.pack()
 w.place(x=0, y=0, width=500)
 root.bind("<Key>", addchar)
 root.bind("<BackSpace>", deletechar)
 root.bind("<Control-s>", savefile)
 root.bind("<Return>", newline)

 root.mainloop()
```

The issue I'm having is that nothing is removed upon pressing delete to remove the last character entered. Any help appreciated. P.S. Ive tried adding a savefile function to save the text to a file but it doesn't work if anyone can help there also, it would again be appreciated :)

Comment: start by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to run your code right know because I'm running out of time. However, first of all, you should not use `pack` and `place` geometry manager in the same `Toplevel`, you should only use one. Second, in your `savefile` function, you did not open the file, so your `file` variable is only a string. You should use something like `file = open(file)`.