# Button didn't raised after clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, binding, keyboard-events

[image: This is my home window.]

This is my home Window of the Application.

[image: After clicking the log in button.]

This is the Window of my application after clicking the LOG IN button.

Now, as you could see that the button is not raised.

I am attaching the code snippet of what happens after clicking the button.

```
    self.org_frame=Frame(self.root,relief=RIDGE,bd=4,bg="#F7DC6F")
    self.org_frame.pack()
    
    self.org_lbl=Label(self.org_frame,text="Organisation ID",fg="black",bg="#F7DC6F" ,font=("helvetica","18","bold"))
    self.org_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)

    self.txt_org=Entry(self.org_frame,width=12,textvariable=self.organisation_id, font=("times new roman",18,"bold"),bd=5)
    self.txt_org.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=10,padx=20)

    self.org_lbl=Label(self.org_frame,text="Password",fg="black",bg="#F7DC6F" ,font=("helvetica","18","bold"))
    self.org_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0)

    self.txt_org=Entry(self.org_frame,width=12,show='•',textvariable=self.organisation_log_password_var, font=("times new roman",18,"bold"),bd=5)
    self.txt_org.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=10,padx=20)
    self.new_btn=Button(self.org_frame,text="New? Sign Up!",width=12,font=("times new roman",16,"bold"),bd=3,cursor="hand2",bg="orange",command=self.new_def)
    self.new_btn.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)   

    self.log_btn=Button(self.org_frame,text="Log In",width=10,font=("times new roman",12,"bold"),bd=3,cursor="hand2",bg="lightgreen",fg="green")
    self.log_btn.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.log_btn.bind("<Button-1>",self.org_log)
    self.root.bind("<Return>",self.org_log)

def new_def(self):   
    messagebox.showinfo("New Account!","To create new Organisation kindly mail us your request\nat aakarsh2504@gmail.com.")  
    
def org_log(self,event):      
    if str(self.organisation_id.get()).lstrip()!="" and str(self.organisation_log_password_var.get()).lstrip()!="":
        try:
            int(self.organisation_id.get())
        
            try:
                con=mysql.connector.connect(host=self.developer_host,user=self.developer_user_id,port=self.developer_port,password=self.developer_password,database=self.developer_database)
                cur=con.cursor()
                
                cur.execute("select host from data where id="+self.organisation_id.get())
                self.host=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select user from data where id="+str(self.organisation_id.get()))
                self.oragnisation_user_id=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select db_password from data where id="+self.organisation_id.get())
                self.organisation_password=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select port from data where id="+str(self.organisation_id.get()))
                self.organisation_port=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select name from data where id="+self.organisation_id.get())
                self.organisation_name=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select database_name from data where id="+str(self.organisation_id.get()))
                self.organisation_database=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select organisation_password from data where id="+str(self.organisation_id.get()))
                self.organisation_log_password=(cur.fetchone())[0]

                cur.execute("select version_required from my_persnol_info where id=1")
                self.required_version=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                
                cur.execute("select developer_email from my_persnol_info where id=1")
                self.developer_email=(cur.fetchone())[0]
                con.commit()
                con.close()
                if self.required_version==self.version:

                    if str(self.organisation_log_password_var.get()).lstrip()==str(self.organisation_log_password):

                        self.org_start()
                    else:
                        messagebox.showerror("Incorrect","Please enter a correct password.")
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("UPDATE",f"You are using and older version of application which is {self.version};\nPlease update it to latest version which is {self.required_version};")
            except TypeError:
                messagebox.showerror("Not Found","Your Organisation was not found")
            except:
                messagebox.showerror("Error!","Please check you Internet connectivity or\ncontact the Admin of your Organisation.")

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error!","Please enter valid Organisation ID.")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Must!","All details are must.")
```

It happens like that when complete details are not entered in the entry box and the message box pops up.

I searched for my issue and got the reason for the same but was unable to find the solution. I am attaching the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354019/tkinter-button-doesn%C2%B4t-change-it%C2%B4s-relief-after-pressing-it) of the issue and its reason. I just need a solution to the issues.

Comment: @acw1668 This is what is seen after closing the message box. While the button is clicked and the message is in the display, the button is raised but when I close the message box and it is removed from display, it gets pressed inside and didn't raise afterwards.

Comment: Add `return "break"` at the end of `org_log()` function will solve the issue.  Also, use `command` option instead of `bind()` to trigger `org_log()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return "break" at the end of org_log() function will solve the issue.