# Why delete(0, tk.END) leaves a character in my entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, qr-code

The script aims to read a QR code so the user does not have to press the Enter key, nor to push any button.
I am reading the qr-code character by character; it contains a "." to indicate the end of the string, like: "012-ABCDE."
The script works just fine even when used continuously and the dot is still in the entry. Can anybody help me to eliminate that dot, please?

```
import tkinter as tk
import string

class mainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, controller):
        askForQRCode(self, controller)

    def processQRCode(self, qrCode):        
        print('processing QR code {}'.format(qrCode))


class askForQRCode(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.parent      = parent
        self.givenString = ''

        #PANEL QR CODE
        panelQRCode = tk.PanedWindow(controller)
        panelQRCode.pack(fill='both', padx=7)
        # ... 

        #SUBJECT
        fSubject = tk.LabelFrame(panelQRCode, text='Subject ID')
        panelQRCode.add(fSubject, stretch='always')
        label = tk.Label(fSubject, text='QR Code')
        label.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=1)
        self.qrCodeEntry = tk.Entry(fSubject)
        self.qrCodeEntry.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=3, padx=7)
        self.qrCodeEntry.focus_force()
        self.qrCodeEntry.bind('<Key>', self.onQREntry)

    def onQREntry(self, event):
        theChar = event.char.upper()
        list1   = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
        list2   = ['-','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        if theChar in list1 or theChar in list2:
            self.givenString = self.givenString + theChar

        elif theChar == '.':
            self.qrCodeEntry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.parent.processQRCode(self.givenString)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('dummy')
    theMainWindow = mainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try binding to `<KeyRelease>` instead of `<Key>` to see if that helps.

Comment: It works! Thank you, Bryan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<Key>` binding happens before the default action of the widget (ie: before the character is actually inserted into the widget).

A simple solution is to bind to `<KeyRelease>`, which gives the default action (bound to `<KeyPress>`) a chance to be fully processed before your custom code.

For a more thorough explanation of how events are processed, see this answer: [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200)

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. That link with your explanation is very helpful as well.