# The text widget insert method of tkinter not working

Tags: python, tkinter, insert

I have been working on one application where in I want to autocomplete things like brackets round curly square. I had done that using the insert method of tkinter with the `tk.INSERT` constant as index like so:

```
def autocomplete(self, val) :
    if val == '(' :
        self.insert(tk.INSERT, ')')
    elif val == '{' :
        self.insert(tk.INSERT, '}')
    elif val == '[' :
        self.insert(tk.INSERT, ']')
    elif val == '\'' :
        self.insert(tk.INSERT, '\'')
        self.mark_set('sentinel', str(float(self.index(tk.INSERT)) - 0.1))
    elif val == '\"' :
        self.insert(tk.INSERT, '\"')
        self.mark_set('sentinel', str(float(self.index(tk.INSERT)) - 0.1))
    elif val == ':' :
        text = self.get(1.0, tk.INSERT).strip().replace(' ', '')
        
        if text[(text.index(':') - 1) : text.index(':')] == ')' :
            self.insert(tk.INSERT, '\n\t')
    return
```

This is a function which is within a text widget where the init has the following bindings attached:

```
self.bind('(', lambda x : self.autocomplete('('))
self.bind('{', lambda x : self.autocomplete('{'))
self.bind('[', lambda x : self.autocomplete('['))
self.bind(':', lambda x : self.autocomplete(':'))
self.bind('\'', lambda x : self.autocomplete('\''))
self.bind('\"', lambda x : self.autocomplete('\"'))
```

And when I type any of these like lets take the e.g. of brackets, then it shows the output somewhat not right.

```
)(
```

Here is also a snapshot of the same:
[image: The text widget's actual snapshot of the problem]

You see I want the other bracket to appear at the end but it does not.

Comment: The problem is related to the order that events are processed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200 for a description.

Comment: Thx alot I finally understood how it works i thought it executed it after detecting the event.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you wrote. It _does_ execute after it detects the event.

Comment: hmm, maybe I understood it wrong, gotta get back learning then! Cya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the binding is triggered before the character is inserted in the text widget. To fix this you can bind to '<KeyRelease-..>' instead, where `..` needs to be replaced by the keysym.

```
self.bind('<KeyRelease-parenleft>', lambda x : self.autocomplete('('))
self.bind('<KeyRelease-braceleft>', lambda x : self.autocomplete('{'))
self.bind('<KeyRelease-bracketleft>', lambda x : self.autocomplete('['))
self.bind('<KeyRelease-colon>', lambda x : self.autocomplete(':'))
self.bind('<KeyRelease-apostrophe>', lambda x : self.autocomplete('\''))
self.bind('<KeyRelease-quotedbl>', lambda x : self.autocomplete('\"'))
```

The keysym of special characters are not always the same for all OS, so here is a trick to find the keysym of any key on your system:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', lambda ev: print(ev.keysym))
root.mainloop()
```

Just press the key to get the keysym

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "apostrophe"

Comment: is the event binding KeyRelease-( or something like that?

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer The event binding is `'<KeyRelease-a>'` where you need to replace 'a' by the keysym of the key (which might change with the OS for special keys). In my case `bind('<KeyRelease-(>', ...)` gives me a `TclError: bad event type or keysym "("`, I need to use 'parenleft'  instead. You need to find what is the correct keysym for the quote for your system.

Comment: actually paren left was just an example the apostrophe is the one causing problem as you may see in the error, also if you know any link to find the keysms it will be really helpful.

Comment: Ohk nevermind I found it manually testing, its <KeywordRelease-\'> for Windows just incase someone else needs it.

Comment: Thx alot for that extra tip in the edit it will rly help me figure these out with other keys.