# Weird behavior of pyperclip

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyperclip

I am trying to copy the selected word from **Text** widget in **Tkinter**. Copying text using `pyperclip.copy(text)` worked perfectly but when I try to paste the copied text using `pyperclip.paste()` but got `᥈H֛` as output. I don't how this has happened and what causes this to happen.

**System: Windows 10**

**Python Version: 3.7.8**

**Code Snippet**

```py
def get_selected_text(self):
    '''Return the selected text if selection is available'''

    try:
        return self.text_widget.get('sel.first', 'sel.last').strip().strip('\n')

    except TclError:
        if 'found' in self.text_widget.tag_names():
            return self.text_widget.get('found.first', 'found.last').strip().strip('\n')

def copy(self, event=None):
    '''Copy functionality when user clicks cut option or presses Ctrl+C'''

    text = self.get_selected_text()
    pyperclip.copy(text)

def paste(self, event=None):
    '''Cut functionality when user clicks cut option or presses Ctrl+X'''

    cursor_pos = self.text_widget.index('insert')
    print(pyperclip.paste())   # Getting weird value '䯀͏H؂' but when called inside copy function then I get the exact value but not in this function
    self.text_widget.insert(cursor_pos, pyperclip.paste())
    self.text_widget.see(cursor_pos)

    return 'break'
```

[Output Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q106jdrjOwlpi70vQU3obSD2J8-hN69f/view?usp=sharing)

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the problem of the pyperclip. The real problem lies in my code itself. So, the problem was that I have bind `ctrl+c` to copy and `ctrl+X` to cut text.
[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200) if `return break` not found in the function then the default binding by the widget and the custom binding gets executed which means when I press `'Ctrl+X` then `paste` function is executed before the default binding and when default binding by the text widget itself then **the weird text gets printed `could not figure why this happens`**

But adding `return break` at the end of `copy, cut and paste` function solved my problem.