# tkinter keeps \n in text widget even after deleting

Tags: python, tkinter

i used `.bind` on a Text widget to delete all content when pressing the `Return` key, but the cursor wont reset to its starting position.

the code is as follows:

```
def send_message(event=None):
    msg = msg_bar.get(1.0, tk.END)
    print(tk.END)
    msg_bar.delete(1.0, tk.END) 

msg_bar = tk.Text(msg_frame) 
msg_bar.bind('<Return>', send_message)
```

i even tried using `msg = msg.strip('\n')` to no avail.

does `tk.END` ignore `\n`? if so how can i make sure the cursor is set correctly to the starting position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding happens before the default behavior of inserting a newline. You delete all of the characters, your function returns, and then the default behavior of tkinter will insert a newline.

You want to prevent the default behavior in this case, so your function needs to return the string "break":

```
def send_message(event=None):
    msg = msg_bar.get(1.0, tk.END)
    print(tk.END)
    msg_bar.delete(1.0, tk.END) 
    return "break"
```

Comment: it works, thanks!
but how exactly does returning "break" prevent the insertion of the newline?

Comment: @EricParker: this explanation goes into a fair amount of detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432