# Python Tkinter on <key>-Event entry.get() is lagging behind

Tags: python, tkinter, events, binding

I have an issue with the Event-Handling. My Code is as follows:

```
import tkinter

def my_function(event):
    print("Event Char: " + event.char)
    print("Input Field: " + my_input.get())

window = tkinter.Tk()
my_input = tkinter.Entry()
my_input.bind("<Key>", my_function)
my_input.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

If I run my programm and enter the letters a, b , c in sequence, then my prints are, as follows:
[image: Console Output]

I do not understand why `my_input` is lagging behind. Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Thx in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug: The event is triggered before the new character is inserted in the entry field, which is why the entry content is "lagging behind".

To fix this, bind instead to `<KeyRelease>` which is triggered after the character is inserted in the entry field.