# How to detect a change in state of a ttk.Button caused by an event and how to use the .state method?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I would like to simulate the following events:

1. When the app frame resizes, it will toggle a change in state in a `ttk.Button` widget (i.e. `self.bn1`). If it is not in a disabled state, it will change to a disabled state, and vice versa.
2. When the state of `self.bn1` is toggled, it will similarly toggle a change in state in `self.bn2` but in an opposite sense. That is, if `self.bn1` is disabled, `self.bn2` will be enabled, and vice versa. The is the key objective.

For objective 2, I want to use the following approach (I think this is the correct way but do correct me if I am wrong):

```
self.bn1.bind("<Activate>", self._set_bn2_disabled)
self.bn1.bind("<Deactivate>", self._set_bn2_enabled)
```

with the intention to learn how to use the `Activate` and `Deactivate` event types. Their documentation is given in [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html).

Below is my test code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.after_id = None
        self._create_widget()
        self._create_bindings()
        
    def _create_widget(self):
        self.bn1 = ttk.Button(self, text="B1")
        self.bn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="B2")
        self.bn2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
       
    def _create_bindings(self):
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._schedule_event)
        self.bind("<<FrameMoved>>", self._change_bn1_status)
        self.bn1.bind("<Activate>", self._set_bn2_disabled)
        self.bn1.bind("<Deactivate>", self._set_bn2_enabled)

    # Event handlers
    def _schedule_event(self, event):
        if self.after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.after(500, self.event_generate, "<<FrameMoved>>")
        
    def _change_bn1_status(self, event):
        print(f"_change_bn1_status(self, event):")
        print(f"{event.widget=}")
        print(f"{self.bn1.state()=}")
        if self.bn1.state() == () or  self.bn1.state() == ('!disable'):
            self.bn1.state(('disable'))
        elif self.bn1.state() == ('disable'):
            self.bn1.state(['!disable'])

    def _set_bn2_disabled(self, event):
        self.bn2.state(['disabled'])
        print(f"{self.bn2.state()=}")

    def _set_bn2_enabled(self, event):
        self.bn2.state(['!disabled'])
        print(f"{self.bn2.state()=}")
               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, it is experiencing an error with the state command.

```
_change_bn1_status(self, event):
event.widget=<__main__.App object .!app>
self.bn1.state()=()
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/user/Coding/test.py", line 36, in _change_bn1_status
    self.bn1.state(('disable'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/ttk.py", line 588, in state
    return self.tk.splitlist(str(self.tk.call(self._w, "state", statespec)))
_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name d
```

Documentation for handling state query of a ttk widget is given by the `.state` method described in [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Widget.html).

**Update:**

Following the comment by @Tranbi, I have revised the `self._change_bn1_status` method to:

```
def _change_bn1_status(self, event):
    print(f"\nBefore: {self.bn1.state()=}")
    if self.bn1.state() == ():
        self.bn1.state(['disabled'])
    elif 'disabled' in self.bn1.state():
        self.bn1.state(['!disabled'])
    print(f"After: {self.bn1.state()=}")
```

The state of `self.bn1` is toggling correctly but not `self.bn2`. How do I do this?

Comment: You have several typos: it should be `disabled` and not `disable`. Also `self.bn1.state(['disabled'])` instead of `self.bn1.state(('disable'))` (square brackets). Finally `self.bn1.state()` returns a tuple so you comparisons won't work. Try `'!disabled' in self.bn1.state()` instead

Comment: @Tranbi Thanks for the corrections. I fixed mistakes 1, 2 & 3. But I can't get `self.bn2` to toggle its state. How can I do that? Am i using a wrong event type?

Comment: If those events `<Activate>` and `<Deactivate>` are not generated by `self.bn1` due to change of state, the state of `self.bn2` will not be changed because the corresponding callback is not executed.  Better change state of `self.bn2` inside `_change_bn1_status()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I hear you. However, this test code's main objective is to understand how to detect state changes in a `ttk.Button` widget that is caused by the event triggered in another widget (which in the real case is at a different hierarchical level). I was hoping that binding the `<Activate>` and `<Deactivate>` event types to `self.bn1` was the right way to do this but I just can't figure out why it is not working. I have looked into the event types specified in `/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py` but have not found an availble alternative.

Comment: @acw1668 I just came across the [explanation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html#M8) of `<Activate>` and `<Deactivate>` in tcl documentation. Looks like it is to be used for tracking the active state of the top-level window and is not appropriate to track the `disabled` and `!disabled` state of a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating the comments of @acw1668 and @Tranbi, and [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593192/5722359) by @ByranOakley on virtual events, and further research, I have revised my test code to what is shown below. The key point is that **virtual events** have to be created/used to detect a change in the state of a `ttk.Button` that is caused by an event.

When declaring a virtual event, I discovered that there needs to be consistency in the syntax. If it is to be declared from `self.bn1`, the `.event_generate` methods should be declared from it and its corresponding `.bind` method be declared from it too. However, if the `.event_generate` method is declared from `self`, the `.bind` method should be declared from `self` instead of `self.bn1`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.after_id = None
        self._create_widget()
        self._create_bindings()
        
    def _create_widget(self):
        self.bn1 = ttk.Button(self, text="B1")
        self.bn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="B2")
        self.bn2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
       
    def _create_bindings(self):
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._schedule_event)
        self.bind("<<FrameMoved>>", self._change_bn1_status)
        self.bn1.bind("<<Enabled>>", self._set_bn2_disabled)  # new
        self.bn1.bind("<<Disabled>>", self._set_bn2_enabled)  # new
        

    # Event handlers
    def _schedule_event(self, event):
        if self.after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.after(500, self.event_generate, "<<FrameMoved>>")
        
    def _change_bn1_status(self, event):
        print(f"\nBefore: {self.bn1.state()=}")
        if self.bn1.state() == () :
            self.bn1.state(['disabled'])  # corrected typo
            self.bn1.after_idle(self.bn1.event_generate, "<<Disabled>>")  # new
        elif 'disabled' in self.bn1.state():  # corrected syntax
            self.bn1.state(['!disabled'])  # corrected typo
            self.bn1.after_idle(self.bn1.event_generate, "<<Enabled>>")  # new
        print(f"After: {self.bn1.state()=}")

    def _set_bn2_disabled(self, event):
        self.bn2.state(['disabled'])
        print(f"\n{self.bn2.state()=}")

    def _set_bn2_enabled(self, event):
        self.bn2.state(['!disabled'])
        print(f"\n{self.bn2.state()=}")
               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Toggling state]