# Python Tkinter - Text widget runnig function before inserting key

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to execute function after pressing key. Problem is if I use this code:

```
text = tk.Text(root)
text.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda event:print(text.get(1.0, tk.END)))
text.pack()
```

When I press first key, nothing is printed. It executes my functions before inserting character, how I can avoid that ? Whitout using `<KeyRelease>`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple technique is to run your code with `after_idle`, which means it runs when `mainloop` has processed all pending events.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def do_something():
    print(text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda event: root.after_idle(do_something))
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

For a deeper explanation of why your binding seems to lag behind what you type by one character see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200) to the question [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter). The question asks about an `Entry` widget but the binding mechanism is the same for all widgets.

Comment: Thank you it's perfectly working, I'm just suprised we can pass argument or something while binding for change this and choose to run function after or before widget events...