# Auto Bracket Closing in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress

I'm making a code editor and everything is good!
But I want to make a feature which **auto closes your bracket** (testing with letter 'a').
Here is my code:
(bracket close part)

st is my scolled text and self is the root window, I am testing with when you press 'a' but **it inserts the bracket before the key ('a') is added into the text box.**

```
#bracket open and close

    def bo(event):
      print("hello")
      self.st.insert(END, ")")
      
      return

    
    self.st.bind('<KeyPress-a>', bo)
```

**Thank you!** Have a good day!

Comment: This answer explains exactly what is happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `KeyRelease` event instead, otherwise your function call is executed before the actual letter is inserted into your Text widget.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, END

def bo(event):
    st.insert(END, ")")

root = Tk()
st = Text(root)
st.bind("<KeyRelease-a>", bo)
st.pack()
root.mainloop()
```