# Python Tkinter issues about special keyboarts inputs: characters and shortcuts

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

The context. I'm making a NotePad app to replace the windows notepad. But I have some problems with the inputs:

■ A good number of functions are registered to allow shortcuts. But some of them do different tasks for example "control + i" inserts a tab instead do what I defined. **How I can change or disable this default behaviour?**

```
    self.__root.bind("<Control-b>", self.__function_a)
    self.__root.bind("<Control-i>", self.__function_b)   # This don't work
    self.__root.bind("<Control-d>", self.__function_c)   # This don't work
    self.__root.bind("<Control-r>", self.__function_d)
```

■ Secondly, I have a personal keyboard layer, which allows to me have an English keyboard with characters such ñ, ¿,¡ but I added others more special like ●░▒▓█•º■▪…→đç☑❎, etc... It's made me easier to write in different languages, take notes or whatever. I can use this with any other app less Tkinder, which only prints these characters instead:  "¦", "?". **Exist and how I could make my app compatible with the addition of these special characters ??**

● I used Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 .

● The Note pad is basically a text area but I notice this doesn't work in others tkinter apps:
class Notepad:

```
__root = Tk() 
__text_area = Text(__root)
__scrollbar = Scrollbar(__text_area)
__menu_bar = Menu(__root)
```

● Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: As for overriding the default behavior, your bound functions need to return the string "break". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432 for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again Bryan. And allow me an excuse for double questions. I will try to formulate better the questions in only one sentence the next time.