# Creating a responsive layout, avoid infinite Configure loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a responsive layout where the content of the app changes depending on the width of the window (basically like any website works). The code I have so far is this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, start_size, min_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Responsive layout')
        self.geometry(f'{start_size[0]}x{start_size[1]}')
        self.minsize(min_size[0],min_size[1])
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        size_notifier = SizeNotifier(self, {300: self.create_small_layout, 600: self.create_medium_layout}, min_size[0])
        self.mainloop()

    def create_small_layout(self):
        self.frame.pack_forget()
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 1', background = 'red').pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 2', background = 'green').pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 3', background = 'blue').pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 4', background = 'yellow').pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        self.frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

    def create_medium_layout(self):
        self.frame.pack_forget()
        
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.frame.rowconfigure((0,1), weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 1', background = 'red').grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew') # sticky = 'nsew' causes configure loop
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 2', background = 'green').grid(column = 1, row = 0)
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 3', background = 'blue').grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        ttk.Label(self.frame, text = 'Label 4', background = 'yellow').grid(column = 1, row = 1)

class SizeNotifier:
    def __init__(self, window, size_dict, min_width):
        self.window = window
        self.min_width = min_width
        self.size_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(size_dict.items())}
        self.current_min_size = None
        self.window.bind('<Configure>', self.check)


    def check(self, event):
        checked_size = None
        window_width = event.width
        if window_width >= self.min_width:
            for min_size in self.size_dict:
                delta = window_width - min_size
                if delta >= 0:
                    checked_size = min_size

            if checked_size != self.current_min_size:
                self.current_min_size = checked_size
                print(self.current_min_size) # infinite loop visible here -> print never stops 
                self.size_dict[self.current_min_size]()

app = App((400,300), (300,300))
```

The basic idea is this: There are 2 functions that create different layouts (create_small_layout and create_medium_layout) and the app hides/reveals one of them depending on the app width. Getting the width of the application is handled by the SizeNotifier class, the logic in there was added to only trigger a layout build function when a new minimum size was reached.

This entire thing works to a degree: In the create_medium_layout function, where I use the grid layout methods, things do work without the sticky argument. However, once I stick a widget to all sides of a cell (so 'nsew') configure is thrown into an infinite loop and the app stops displaying anything. using sticky with just 3 sides or less is fine though.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind to a root window, the binding applies to all widgets. This is because bindings don't actually get added to a widget, but rather to a *binding tag*. Every widget has a set of binding tags, and every widget has the root window as one of its binding tags.

For more information about bind tags see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200) to the question [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200). Also, the canonical description can be found in the [tcl/tk manual page on the bind command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/bind.htm#M4).

That means that `self.check` will be called when the root window resizes, and it will also be called once when every frame and label resizes. Since you're using `event.width`, sometimes that value will be the width of the window and sometimes it will be the width of a frame or label.

You should modify your `check` feature to only run when it is called due to the window itself changing size. In your case you can add a check like the following:

```
def check(self, event):
    if event.widget == self.window:
        ...
```