# How do I use bindtags with ttk.Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541262/2684771), I can setup bindtags to get events that include the keypress that activated the event.

When I change `tk.Entry` to `ttk.Entry`, the events still work but I am unable to select the entry contents or click to give `ttk.Entry` focus. Tabbing between fields does select all, but selecting part contents does not work.

How does bintags differ with ttk widgets? or how do I configure ttk bindtags to allow mouse click and content selection?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

status = ttk.Label(root)
status.grid(row=2, column=0)

def OnKeyPress(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    string="value of %s is '%s'" % (event.widget._name, value)
    status.configure(text=string)

tk_entry = tk.Entry(root, name="tk_entry")
tk_entry.bindtags(('Entry', '.tk_entry', '.', 'all'))
tk_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
tk_entry.bind("<KeyPress>", OnKeyPress)

# this entry content is unable to be selected
ttk_entry = ttk.Entry(root, name="ttk_entry")
ttk_entry.bindtags(('Entry', '.ttk_entry', '.', 'all'))
ttk_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
ttk_entry.bind("<KeyPress>", OnKeyPress)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider to include your system information and patch level of libraries in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given the entry the bindtags for a `tk.Entry` widget. You should give it the bindtags for the `ttk.Entry` widget instead:

```
ttk_entry.bindtags(('TEntry', '.ttk_entry', '.', 'all'))
#                    ^^^^^^
```