# Remove default shortcut

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

I want to implement function for line duplicate(CTRL+D).
There is a default binding already in text widget

As per documentation [https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.html](https://stackoverflow.com)
it says:

> **Control-d deletes the character to the right of the insertion cursor.**

No matter what to do it still performs besides my function.
How to disable it?

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<Control-d>", self.duplicate_line)
        self.text.bind("<Control-D>", self.duplicate_line)

    def duplicate_line(self, event=None):
        line = self.text.get("current linestart", "current lineend+1c")
        self.text.insert("insert lineend+1c", line)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Thanks

With unbind at the start didn't work.

```
        self.text.unbind("<Control-d>")
        self.text.unbind("<Control-D>")
```

Comment: At the end of `duplicate-line` - `return "break"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter)