# Why binded function on Entry widget keyPress doesn't return the current text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Sorry, if this is a duplicate or obvious question. So I simply wrote this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


def on_key_pressed(e: tk.Event):
    print(text_field.get())


text_field = tk.Entry()
text_field.pack()
text_field.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_pressed)
```

When I press key, it outputs like a previous typed string and not considering the key that has just been pressed. I guess maybe this is because the event keyPress happens too fast, and Entry didn't register this new change yet.

Am I right, or what will be a better explanation of this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your binding happens before the default binding, and it's the default binding that causes the character to be entered into the widget.

See [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200) for more information

Comment: Thank you! So, if I rebind tags, so that first tag will be a class and than a widget itself, it will show correctly. So just add something like this: `text_field.bindtags(('Entry', '.!entry', '.', 'all'))`

Comment: @DanyaK: that means that bindings on the widget can't override the default bindings, but if you don't need to do any overriding, that would work.

Comment: oh, l see. I think I will need to do overriding. Is there are a way to do an exception for a set or get functions of Entry in bindtags? Or what should I use instead?

Comment: Or does the third example from your link creates what I needed? So just a new tag could be created after Entry class tag and it binds to the function? Will I be able to do overriding?

Comment: @DanyaK: without knowing the actual problem  you're trying to solve, it's difficult to answer your question. Your question should explain why you need to call `get()` on a keypress. Are you doing validation? Are you taking the character and passing it to some other device? Something else?

Comment: I am still trying to make an expandable Entry widget, so that it will always match the text until some width(my previous questions with a downvote). In order to do that, I at least need to know the text in Entry just after the person typed something. I have descovered, that if Entry width set to 0 or less it will start to become expandable without any manipulations. But still need to think, how to set "up" and "down" limits. Probably will need to know the current text