# tkinter: map key to other letters/ciphres

Tags: python, events, tkinter

Is there a way to map key events to other letters. This is for a
convienient way to put ciphres in an entry field:

An example: My laptop has no extra keys for ciphres on the keyboard,
but i often had to do number input. So i thought it would be nice
to have an entry which changes letters in ciphres:

```
e -> 1
z -> 2
d -> 3
v -> 4
f -> 5
...
```

I tried many things:

- a label simulates a entry, but theres a problem with the  event,
  because this event isnt supported by the label widget.
- by the entry `<Key>` event i couldn't change the input in the entry. A pressed `e` will always displayed in the entry. (i used the propagated validation method by tkinter!).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your attempt to bind to `<Key>` failed is probably because you failed to do `return "break"` after processing the keystroke.

You can create your own binding for any key on the keyboard. For example, to change "e" to do anything you want, do `self.entry.bind("<e>", ...)`. Then, in the binding you can insert whatever you want. If you do `return "break"`, then the default handling of the key will be suppressed.

If you want to set up a mapping in a dictionary, you can bind to `"<Key>"`. Here's a quick example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    map = {"e": "1",
           "z": "2",
           "v": "3",
           # ... and so on
           }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.bind("<Key>", self.keymap)

    def keymap(self, event):
        if event.char in self.map:
            self.entry.insert("insert", self.map[event.char])
            return "break"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you're right - i didn't do a ``return "break"``. I tested it with that and it solves - a part - of the problem. I don't understand the ``return "break"`` so far but i think it's a tcl interna - right?

Comment: Tkinter has the notion of "bind tags" (or bindtags) -- it defines an order for processing events. Doing "return 'break'" stops the processing of an event -- no more tags for the current event will be processed. The bind tag that handles the default behavior of an event falls _after_ the tag for the widget itself. Thus, if you put a binding on a widget and then do `return "break"` you prevent the default binding from happening. For more information see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7432

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know is to intercept the input using the string variable that you've assigned to the entry widget.  One of the things that you can do with such variables is execute a function or method whenever that variable changes, and you can use that function/method to modify the entry contents.  Here's a quick example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class EntryHack(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.pack(side="left")
        self.entry = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry.pack(side="left")
        self.entry_var = StringVar()
        self.entry_var.trace_variable("w", self.changed)
        self.entry["textvariable"] = self.entry_var

    def changed(self, *args):
        """Intercept changes"""
        value = self.entry_var.get()
        changed = False
        frm = "zxcasdqwe"
        to = "123456789"
        if not value.isdigit():
            changed = True
            new = ""
            for char in value:
                if char.isdigit() or char not in frm:
                    new += char
                else:
                    new += to[frm.index(char)]
            value = new
        if changed:
            self.entry_var.set(value)

root = Tk()
app = EntryHack(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The nice thing about the `trace_variable` assignment is that the function/method that you give it *will* be called when you type something into the field, but *will not* be called when you make manual changes to the variable, thus avoiding an endless loop.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the _easiest_, but it is one way to approach the problem.

Comment: Edited to clarify that it's the easiest way that I currently know.

Comment: I try some code on that basis. i will post my own solution as soon as possible - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok my own solution...

thanks to @Justin S Barrett and to @Brian Oakley.

According to @Brian Oakley's hint i solved my problem:

```
class DigitEntry(Frame):
    mapping = {
        "o": "0",
        "e": "1",
        "z": "2",
        "d": "3",
        "v": "4",
        "f": "5",
        "s": "6",
        "i": "7",
        "a": "8",
        "n": "9",
        ",": ".",

        "0": "0",
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2",
        "3": "3",
        "4": "4",
        "5": "5",
        "6": "6",
        "7": "7",
        "8": "8",
        "9": "9",
        ".": "."
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry.pack(fill="x")

        self.entry.bind("<Key>", self.keymap)
        self.entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.check)

    def check(self, event):
        """if checks are necessary
        """
        pass

    def keymap(self, event):
        """ do mappings, pass allowed inputs and block the rest.
        """
        if event.char in self.mapping:
            self.entry.insert("insert", self.mapping[event.char])
            return "break"
        elif event.keysym in ["BackSpace", "Tab"]:
            pass
        else:
            self.entry.insert("insert", "")
            return "break"


class PointsEntry(DigitEntry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DigitEntry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def check(self, event):
        value = self.entry.get()

        if value.find(".") >= 0:
            if not (value[-1] == "." or value[-2:] == ".5"):
                err = value + " bad frac digit"
                self.entry.delete(0, "end")
                self.entry["bg"] = "red"
                self.entry.insert("insert", err)

            elif value[-1] == ".":
                self.entry.insert("insert", "5")
                if len(value) == 1:
                    self.entry.insert(0, "0")
                return "break"
```

Comment: there's no point in the final else in the `keymap` function -- you're just replicating the default behavior. You can remove those three lines and the program will still work the way you expect. In fact, I think your solution breaks the behavior of the back and forward arrow keys; by removing that else block the arrow keys will work as expected.

Comment: i need this else branch because the keys "q,w,..." must be blocked! if special keys are needed they have to be listed in the ``elif event.keysym in [...]`` branch.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. You can remove the insert command and just return "break". Inserting an empty string serves no purpose; it's not a requirement for a key binding that it has to call the insert function.

Comment: Even though you wrote your own code for your specific situation, it's based primarily on the tips from @BryanOakley, as you indicated.  In that light, methinks his answer deserves to be marked as the accepted solution.