# Why Text cursor coordinates are not updated correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, text, tkinter

To create a simple line-column counter for my text editor, I decided to simply use the `index` function of the `tkinter.Text` widget. In fact, the `index` function returns a string representing the line and column of the coordinates passed as argument to it.

Specifically, I am using `cursor_pos = text.index(tkinter.INSERT)` to get the index of the cursor, since, from the [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) website on `tkinter.INSERT`:

> tkinter.INSERT corresponds to the insertion cursor.

The problem is that `tkinter.INSERT` seems to give me the last cursor position until I move the cursor with the arrows (for example).

This is the function that handles the count of the lines and columns:

```
def on_key_pressed(self, event=None):
    """Docs """
    if self.tpane is not None:
        print(self.lines, self.columns)

        self.tpane.update()
        cursor_pos = self.tpane._tabs[self.tpane.selected()].text.index(tkinter.INSERT)
        self.lines = int(cursor_pos.split('.')[0])
        self.columns = int(cursor_pos.split('.')[1])
        print(self.lines, self.columns)
        self.line_c.config(text='Lines: ' + str(self.lines))
        self.col_c.config(text='Columns: ' + str(self.columns))

        self.update()
```

I don't know if you can understand the situation... When I first type a letter on the editor, the `self.columns` variable does not update to 1 (remains 0) until I write the second letter, where it updates to 1, and so on. But there's a trick to make it update without writing a new letter. Once written the first letter, if I move the cursor with the arrows, it updates the `self.columns` to actually 1.

Another problem is when I try to delete a existent character. For example, if I have 3 characters (and suppose I have `self.columns` to 3), and I press `delete`, `self.columns` update inexplicably to `4`, and if I try to remove another character, at this point, it updates to 3.

This problems exists also for the `self.lines` in the `on_key_pressed` event handler. I am not sure if this is supposed to happen, and if yes, then I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your custom binding fire before the built-in bindings, and it is the built-in bindings that actually modify the widget and change the cursor position.

You can change the order by leveraging bindtags. For more information see this question: [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541262/7432)

For an example of how to change the bindtags, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7432

If you don't want to deal with bindtags, you can bind to `<KeyRelease>`. Built-in bindings happen on a key *press*, so the *release* binding will always fire after the widget has been updated.