# Confused about Tkinter bind_class

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I define GCanvas, an extension of Canvas. My intention is to bind to GCanvas at the class level. It isn't working.

I also tried to bind to tk.Canvas and it doesn't work either. Binding to `root` or to the GCanvas instance works fine. (Neither of this alternatives is useful to me, but I just tried them to see what happened.). Running OS X, El Capitan.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GCanvas(tk.Canvas, object):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def enter(e):
        print "enter", e.widget, e.x, e.y

    @staticmethod
    def leave(e):
        print "leave", e.widget

    @staticmethod
    def motion(e):
        print "motion", e.widget, e.x, e.y

approach = "bindinstance"

root = tk.Tk()
gc = GCanvas(root, width=400, height=300)
print "root is", root, "gc is", gc
gc.pack()

if approach == "bindGCanvas":
    print "binding to GCanvas"
    root.bind_class(GCanvas, '<Enter>', GCanvas.enter)
    root.bind_class(GCanvas, '<Leave>', GCanvas.leave)
    #root.bind_class(GCanvas, '<Motion>', GCanvas.motion)
elif approach == "bindCanvas":
    print "binding to Canvas"
    root.bind_class(tk.Canvas, '<Enter>', GCanvas.enter)
    root.bind_class(tk.Canvas, '<Leave>', GCanvas.leave)
    #root.bind_class(tk.Canvas, '<Motion>', GCanvas.motion)
elif approach == "bindinstance":
    print "binding to instance"
    gc.bind('<Enter>', GCanvas.enter)
    gc.bind('<Leave>', GCanvas.leave)
    #gc.bind('<Motion>', GCanvas.motion)
else:
    print "binding to root"
    root.bind('<Enter>', GCanvas.enter)
    root.bind('<Leave>', GCanvas.leave)
    #root.bind('<Motion>', GCanvas.motion)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "class" in `bind_class` refers to the internal class name used by the tk library, not the python class name. More precisely, in this context it refers to a *bind tag*, which happens to be the same name as the tk class, which also happens to be the same name as one of the core Tkinter classes (eg: `Toplevel`, `Canvas`, etc).

To bind to `GCanvas` at the class level, the simplest thing would be to add a bind tag named `GCanvas` to your canvas, as in the following example:

```
class GCanvas(tk.Canvas, object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        ...
        # get the current bind tags
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())

        # add our custom bind tag before the Canvas bind tag
        index = bindtags.index("Canvas")
        bindtags.insert(index, "GCanvas")

        # save the bind tags back to the widget
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
```

You can then use `bind_class` like so:

```
root.bind_class("GCanvas", "<Enter>", GCanvas.enter)
root.bind_class("GCanvas", "<Leave>", GCanvas.leave)
```

For more information about bind tags, see these answers to some other tkinter questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7432

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need to define a Python class at all; I just need to add to my canvases a unique bindtag, right?

Comment: @Eduardo: correct. I recommend using a class to create a new type of canvas, but strictly speaking you don't _need_ to.

Comment: What if I had a custom `Frame` and inside this frame, there is other widgets. How would I make a bind such that the bind works where I click on this custom frame?

Comment: @CoolCloud: you can add the `GCanvas` tag to the bindtags of the frame.

Comment: I did add that, but when `Label` take focus inside the frame, the bindings no longer work

Comment: @CoolCloud: that's because the bindings only work for widgets with the bindtag. You asked about clicking on the frame, not on clicking on a label in the frame.

Comment: Hmmm okay, ill add for all/each widget

Answer (score 0):

An express solution I found to resolve a binding conflict between two text() boxes.
Listing the `bindtags` to sort the path of the widget. The first occurrence in list. The binding was triggered on both widgets at the same time.

```
self.frame2 = Frame(self)
self.frame2.pack()
self.textDomain = Text(self.frame2, width=21, height=10, wrap=WORD, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
self.textDomain.pack()
self.bindtags = list(self.textDomain.bindtags())
self.textDomain.bind_class(str(self.bindtags[0]), "<Return>", lambda _: self.verifytextBox("textDomain"))
self.textDomain.bind_class(str(self.bindtags[0]), "<Leave>", lambda _: self.verifytextBox("textDomain"))
self.textExtension = Text(self.frame2, width=21, height=10, wrap=WORD, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)
self.textExtension.pack()
self.bindtags = list(self.textExtension.bindtags())
self.textExtension.bind_class(str(self.bindtags[0]), "<Return>", lambda _: self.verifytextBox("textExtension"))
self.textExtension.bind_class(str(self.bindtags[0]), "<Leave>", lambda _: self.verifytextBox("textExtension"))
```