# tkinter wait_variable in mouse event

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to do some real-time updating of my GUI, but the variables seem to update AFTER the event happens, meaning it updates the previous button press. I know it has something to do with the `wait_variable()` function but the documentation is hazy, and the other post about it here didn't seem to help me. Here's the relevant code:

**EDIT**: Working example

```
from tkinter import *
import json
import os

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        master.title("Catalogue")
        master.geometry("500x300")
        self.categories = ["Top","Bottom","Dress","Outerwear"]
        self.setup_filters()

    def setup_filters(self):
        self.filter_categs_vars = []
        self.filter_checks = []
        for i in range(len(self.categories)):
            self.filter_categs_vars.append(IntVar())
            self.filter_checks.append(Checkbutton(root,variable=self.filter_categs_vars[i],text=self.categories[i]))
            self.filter_checks[i].grid(row=7+i,column=0,sticky=W)
            self.filter_checks[i].select()
            self.filter_checks[i].bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.filter_categ)

    def filter_categ(self, event):
        for i in range(len(self.filter_categs_vars)):
            #self.filter_checks[i].wait_variable(self.filter_categs_vars[i])
            print(self.filter_categs_vars[i].get()) #Debug print

#START PROGRAM
global catalogue 
root = Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to the relevant code.

Comment: All right, thank you! Done.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I think you can still provide a better example that fits [mcve].

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future! Your first suggestion is exactly what I was looking for (and used previously in my code but forgot about!) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

## Analysis

What I believe to be [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the above-mentioned issue:

```
import tkinter as tk


def callback(event):
    #checkbutton.wait_variable(var)
    checkbutton['text'] = var.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check", variable=var,
                                        onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    checkbutton.pack()
    checkbutton.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", callback)

    root.mainloop()
```

This happens simply because the virtual events, for example, the one that sets a `Checkbutton`'s value based on its state (checked / unchecked), are handled *after* events attached with `bind` are handled(See the very last MCVE provided).

For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7032856

---

For the code you've provided, it means that `Checkbutton`'s value won't change until the `bind` event handle `filter_categ` method is finished. But `filter_categ` won't move on unless `Checkbutton`'s value is changed.

Which makes your program to be stuck at a local event loop, waiting for a `'break'`, a `'break'` comes only if the loop is completed. Feels like a paradox.

---

Review the following example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def modify_var(event):
    var.set(random.choice((True, False)))

def callback(event):
    checkbutton.wait_variable(var)
    checkbutton['text'] = var.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check", variable=var,
                                        onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    checkbutton.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    checkbutton.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", callback)

    root.bind_all("<Escape>", modify_var)

    root.mainloop()
```

It has the same paradoxical behavior your code does, but with the only exception, when <kbd>Escape</kbd> is hit, the variable `wait_variable` waits, `var`, is modified, so the local event loop is broken.

---

## Solutions

**By using [`command` option in `Checkbutton`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)**

Replace:

```
self.filter_checks[i].bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.filter_categ)
```

with:

```
self.filter_checks[i]['command'] = self.filter_categ
```

This is by far ***the simplest***. Also, you can overwrite your method definition to:

```
def filter_categ(self):
    ...
```

unless it would be used later on by other events.

Its MCVE:

```
# By using command option in Checkbutton MCVE
import tkinter as tk


def callback():
    checkbutton['text'] = var.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check", variable=var,
                                        onvalue=True, offvalue=False)

    checkbutton['command'] = callback

    checkbutton.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**By using [Tkinter Variable Class and, `trace_add`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)**

replace:

```
self.filter_checks[i].bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.filter_categ)
```

with:

```
self.filter_categs_vars[i].trace_add('write', self.filter_categ)
```

with the above line, `trace_add` will call its callback, `self.filter_categ` with 3 arguments, for which your method needs to accept those arguments as well, whenever the variable it is attached to, `self.filter_categs_vars[i]`, gets modified. Replace:

```
def filter_categ(self, event):
```

with:

```
def filter_categ(self, *args):
```

Its MCVE:

```
# By using Tkinter Variable Class and, trace_add
import tkinter as tk


def callback(*args):
    checkbutton['text'] = var.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check", variable=var,
                                        onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    
    var.trace_add('write', callback)

    checkbutton.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**By shifting the order of event handle sequence**

```
self.filter_checks[i].bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.filter_categ) # this line is not modified
self.filter_checks[i].bindtags((self.filter_checks[i].bindtags()[1:] + self.filter_checks[i].bindtags()[:1]))
```

This makes it so that `"<ButtonRelease-1>"` event is handled the latest, as in `Checkbutton`'s variable value will change before `self.filter_categ` is executed.

Its MCVE:

```
# By shifting the order of event handle sequence MCVE
import tkinter as tk


def callback(event):
    checkbutton['text'] = var.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.BooleanVar()
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Check", variable=var,
                                        onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    checkbutton.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    checkbutton.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", callback)

    # comment the line below out to see the difference
    checkbutton.bindtags((checkbutton.bindtags()[1:] + checkbutton.bindtags()[:1]))

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I tried binding the callback to the button press and the button release to the modify variable, but it doesn't seem to work reliably. Is there another way of automating this without requiring user input?