# Is there a way to bind all keyboard keys to tkinter.Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am actually making a text editor and obviously I needed text coloring for that. It works perfectly, as I was using it in a thread, which makes it lag a lot. I think if I bind it with every key, it'll work, so when any key is pressed (except spacing keys like <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>, etc), it'll check if a python keyword is on the screen and change its color.

I am looking for something like this:

```
textArea.bind("<NonSpacingKeys>", color_coding)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I read this: [How to bind self events in Tkinter Text widget after it will binded by Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501849/how-to-bind-self-events-in-tkinter-text-widget-after-it-will-binded-by-text-widg)

```
textArea.bind("<KeyPress>", color_coding)
```

this worked prefectly