# Call tkinter.Text binds after the text is inputted

Tags: python, tkinter

In my project I'm trying to add matching parentheses as I type into a `tkinter.Text` widget. Basically, when I type `(`, the program automatically inserts `)`.

The only answer I could find for this same issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501849/how-to-bind-self-events-in-tkinter-text-widget-after-it-will-binded-by-text-widg). I tried all three options the selected answer had, and none worked. The answer *is* 10 years old so I thought it would have been outdated.

Here is what I have so far. The code *works*, but the ending-parentheses is inserted before the start-parentheses. (looks like this `)(`.). How can I make the ending-parentheses get inserted *after* the starting one?:

```
text_box.bind("<(>", lambda n: text_box.insert(float(text_box.index("insert")) + 1, ")"))
```

It would also help if the ending-parentheses is put *after* the cursor (to the left of your cursor is `(` and to the right is `)`

Thanks for any answers

Comment: _"The answer is 10 years old so I thought it would have been outdated."_ - no, the answer isn't outdated. This behavior is fundamental to how to works, and hasn't changed in decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert the closing `)` at the insertion position and then move the insertion cursor back 1 character:

```py
def close_parenthese(event):
    logbox.insert("insert", ")") # add the closing )
    logbox.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c") # move back the insertion cursor

text_box.bind("(", close_parenthese)
```

Comment: This technically works, but I still need to find a working way to make binds execute after the text is entered :(