# Tkinter Event Binding

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to make an event fire in a different order. For instance, if I add a `MouseWheel` listener to a `Text` widget, I will get the event before the scrolling has even been applied. Is there a way to make my bind come last?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def wheel(event): print('this will fire before the movement has happened')

t=tk.Text(root)
t.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
t.bind('<MouseWheel>', wheel)

root.mainloop()
```

SIDENOTE: I already have a system where I simply hijack the entire `MouseWheel` event and handle the scroll myself. That's not the answer I'm looking for. I seriously want my event to come after it is handled internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order in which callbacks for a specific event are processed, but you can't change the order of the events themselves.

There's already a question on Stackoverflow that asks something similar, and it has an answer that includes an example that illustrates how to change the order that callbacks are handled. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7432) to the question [How to bind self events in Tkinter Text widget after it will binded by Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501849/how-to-bind-self-events-in-tkinter-text-widget-after-it-will-binded-by-text-widg)

That answer mentions tkinter's *bind tags*. There's another question that goes into a bit of detail about how bindings are processed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432) to the question [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create a proxy and filter the events, as below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from contextlib  import suppress

class Text(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.__handler)
        
        self._p = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._p)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy) 
        
    def _proxy(self, cmd, *args) -> None:
        targ = ""

        with suppress(tk.TclError): targ = self.tk.call((self._p, cmd) + args)
        
        if cmd=='yview' and 'scroll' in args: self.after_idle(self.__handler, None, args)
            
        return targ   
        
    def __handler(self, event, *args) -> None:
        if event: print('from bind')
        else:     print('from proxy')


root = tk.Tk()

t=Text(root)
t.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```